# Create a proxy server

Tags: nginx, proxy, https, http

I want to create a HTTP and HTTPS proxy server, to use with cURL

```
curl -vvv "ifconfig.me" -x user:password@myproxy:8000
```

I am trying Nginx, but I can not get to work **with** user and password, my requirement is protecting with user and password

What software do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a forward proxy software.

NGINX is a reverse proxy which is not what you're looking for.

Also, product recommendations are off-topic on SE so which forward proxy to use is up to you to determine depending on your use case.